# HTML Validation: Using element.validity.typeMismatch and element.validity.tooLong

Tags: html, validation, constraint-validation-api

I have a [JavaScript validation framework](https://github.com/vivin/regula) that I've created and I'm trying to add HTML validation to it. In my framework, validation is accomplished by binding validation-constraints to elements using a `data-` attributes. This is somewhat similar to how HTML validation happens by using attributes like `required`, `min`, `max`, etc.

I have two problems right now. Well, they may not necessarily be problems, but I would like a better understanding of the situation so that I can decide how to move forward.

The first issue I have `element.validity.typeMismatch`, which is set to `true` if the value of the element doesn't match the type of the element. For example, if you have an invalid URL value for an element with `type="url"` or an invalid email for an element with `type="email"`. However, this behavior is inconsistent for something like `type="number"`. The reason the behavior is inconsistent is because the browser *won't let you add invalid values* to an `input` with `type="number"` (through the UI or even through the DOM). Due to this, `element.validity.typeMismatch` is never set to `true` and `element.checkValidity()` always returns `true`. This behavior is inconsistent with the behavior on `type="url"` and `type="email"` where you *can* enter invalid values, and `element.validity.typeMismatch` and `element.checkValidity()` return the expected values.

I have a similar issue with using `maxlength`. There is a `ValidityState` property called `tooLong` at `element.validity.tooLong`. It appears that this value is *never* set to `true` when interacting with an `input` directly from the browser, because you can never enter a value that is longer than the value of* `maxlength`. Furthermore, even though you can set a value *that is longer than* `maxlength` *from the DOM*, `element.validity.tooLong` again, is never set to `true`. So I'm wondering why this property is even there if it is more-or-less useless.

Currently, how is HTML validation expected to behave with these constraints? How can an error message ever be generated for these constraint violations if the browser won't let you enter invalid values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find more clarification on this matter. Both [W3C](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#suffering-from-a-type-mismatch) and [WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#suffering-from-a-type-mismatch) say:

> ***`typeMismatch`***
>
> The control is suffering from a type mismatch.
>
> [...]
>
> ***Suffering from a type mismatch***
>
> When a control that allows arbitrary user input has a value that is not in the correct syntax (E-mail, URL).

So it appears that this value is only set in the case of `type` being set to either `url` or `email`. In all other cases it will not be set because the `input` elements won't allow the user to set their values to invalid ones (manually or programmatically).

Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the issue with `tooLong`; the specification says that this will be set if the input value is too long, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Is there a way to match the `element.validity.typeMismatch` with a css selector?

Comment: And by the way, I found this article that might be helpful in your case: https://css-tricks.com/form-validation-part-3-validity-state-api-polyfill/